# Check for data on canvas and apply class accordingly

Tags: jquery, css, canvas

I am using a jQuery plugin called jqscribble to draw to canvas. I would like to grayscale an icon if nothing is drawn to the canvas. As mentioned in the plugin documentation, I can check this using `$('...').data('jqScribble').blank` and I am using it as such:

```
if ($('#draw').data('jqScribble').blank) {
    $("#pencil").css("filter" , "grayscale(100%)");
} else {
    $("#pencil").css("filter" , "grayscale(0%)");
}
```

This greys out my icon on load, but drawing on the canvas has no effect. Is there a way in which I could check for this continuously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to check is to monitor clicks/touches to the canvas assuming those are the only means to draw onto the canvas (if external data is drawn you can always tap into those functions as well though).

- If a click or touch is detected, mark canvas "tainted"
- When cleared (or saved or other condition), clear taint flag

This way you won't have to pull data from the canvas at all times which has a huge overhead for some type of checks like for example pulling a data-uri and compare it to one that represents an empty canvas.

```js
var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect(),
    dx = rect.left, dy = rect.top,
    isTainted = false,
    isDown = false,
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    save = document.getElementById("save"),
    clr = document.getElementById("clr");

c.onmousedown = function(e) {
  isDown = isTainted = true;    // mark canvas tainted
  status();                     // update ghosted button
  draw(e);                      // draw something...
};
window.onmousemove = function(e) {if (isDown) draw(e)};
window.onmouseup = function() {isDown = false};

clr.onclick = function() {
  isTainted = false;           // clear tainted flag (in this case)
  status();
  c.width = c.width;
};

function draw(e) {ctx.fillRect(e.clientX - dx - 1, e.clientY - dy - 1, 2, 2)}
function status() {save.disabled = !isTainted}
```

```css
#c {background:#ddd}
```

```html
<button id=save disabled>Save</button>
<button id=clr>Clear</button>
<div><canvas id=c width=600 height=600></canvas></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an event listener to run your code each time the canvas is clicked.

```
$("canvas").mousedown( function() {
    if ($('#draw').data('jqScribble').blank) {
        $("#pencil").css("filter" , "grayscale(100%)");
    } else {
        $("#pencil").css("filter" , "grayscale(0%)");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, since you asked, you can also run you code every second with setInterval() for example:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    if ($('#draw').data('jqScribble').blank) {
        $("#pencil").css("filter" , "grayscale(100%)");
    } else {
        $("#pencil").css("filter" , "grayscale(0%)");
    }
}, 1000);
```

just change the number at the end to adjust the interval time in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. `mousedown` seemed to work intermittently, and not on touch at all (I know, I didn't mention this requirement, so not your fault). `click touchstart` seems to do the trick, however?